# Explain the following code?

Tags: c, function, assign

There are several things I don't understand about the below snippet of code (written in C):

```
struct T {
int a;
int *b;
struct T *next;
} ;

struct T *p1;

struct T* (*f)(int, int, struct T*);

struct T* g(int a, int b, struct T* c)
{
    return (a > b ? c : NULL);
}

f = &g;
p1 = (*f)(4,3,p1);
```

In particular, what does this line mean?

```
struct T* (*f)(int, int, struct T*);
```

Is this a function?  If so, why doesn't it have a body, and why are there formal parameter names that appear to be missing?  What does this function return, if it lacks a body?

Also, what is going on with the assignment below?

```
f = &g;
```

Comment: Suggest compiling this and running through a debugger.

Comment: There's a nice tutorial on function pointers here: http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In particular, what does this line mean?

struct T* (*f)(int, int, struct T*);

declares f as a pointer to a function which takes the parameters (int, int, struct T*) and which returns a pointer to a struct T.

> Is this a function?

No.  However, f can point to a function.

> why doesn't it have a body?

As a pointer to a function, it only requires sufficient definition to let the compiler know the prototype of the function it will point to.  In this case, it ends up pointing to the function g; and so it's prototype should match g's definition (or a warning will result).

> why are there formal parameter names that appear to be missing

Names of the arguments are optional for function pointers.  Only the argument types are needed.

> Also, what is going on with the assignment below?

```
f = &g;
```

(function) pointer f is assigned the address of (function) g.

And finally...

```
p1 = (*f)(4,3,p1);
```

The function pointed to by f (ie: g) is called with the values(4,3,p1).  The value returned is placed into p1.

Answer (score 5):

Line `struct T* (*f)(int, int, struct T*);`, Is function pointer,
Where you define pointer to function, Which takes three arguments `(int, int, struct T*)`.

And Code `f = &g;` means you are assigning function pointer `f` with function `g`.

Answer (score 2):

So `f` is a pointer to a function, which takes `int, int, struc T *` and returns a `struct T *`.  `f` is assigned to the address of `g`, which is a common-or-garden function.  Then that line with `p1` is invoking `f()`, which actually invokes `g()`.

BTW, I can seriously recommend Peter van der Linden's book "Deep C Secrets" - very readable, and now released as pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a function pointer variable. Here's [how to parse them](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html):

> struct T* (***f**)(int, int, struct T*);

`f` is a pointer

> struct T* (*f) **(int, int, struct T*)**;

..to a function that takes two `int` arguments and one pointer to `struct T`

> **struct T*** (*f)(int, int, struct T*);

.. and returns a pointer to `struct T`

Now that you know that `f` is a function pointer variable, the meaning of `f = &g;` should be obvious.

*Hint: `g` is a function.*